# Updating records depending on the intersection of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  |    Start   |    End     | Flag1 | Flag2
--------------------------------------------    
1   | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 |   0   |   1
1   | 1900-01-01 | 2000-01-01 |   1   |   0
2   | 2010-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |   0   |   0
```

For any date range of an ID, flags 1 and 2 could be set to 1 or 0. For the first record, he's only flag2. For the second record, he's only flag1.

Is there a way to update the records in a way where the flags are both 1 in the intersection of the start and end dates? Essentially:

```
ID  |    Start   |    End     | Flag1 | Flag2
--------------------------------------------    
1   | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 |   1   |   1
1   | 1900-01-02 | 2000-01-01 |   1   |   0
2   | 2010-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |   0   |   0
```

I have tried using a group by but it doesn't return the result set as expected.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW, howcome your ID column has duplicate values?

Comment: Oh, that ID is not the key, so it can be duplicate.

Comment: Is the following answer useful? If yes, vote up please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **self join** to achieve the desired result.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Flag1 = 1, t1.Flag2 = 1
FROM
mytable t1 join mytable t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.Start_Date = t2.End_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
UPDATE [mytable] SET [flag1] = 1, [flag2] = 1 WHERE [startdate] = [enddate]
```